# Photoshop: How do you pull part of the shapes border to the right?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

## Photoshop: How do you pull part of the  shapes border to the right???

I am trying to pull part of a rounded shapes border to the left to make a triangle like effect, I'm sorry if I explained that bad here is a [Video Link][1] to a video of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example:

[image]

I have drawn 2 rectangles as vector shape layers with black fill. Both have as layer style colored stroke with gradient fill. The stroke is inside the rectangle path.

The rightmost rectangle has got a new anchor point onto the left vertical edge. The original corner is dragged to the right with the anchor editing tool (=white arrow) . Before dragging all anchors were converted to sharp with the anchor type tool to prevent any curvature to appear.

In the video there's in the same place 2 identical rectangles with metallic gradient stroke and chamfered corners.

2 anchors of another rectangle were selected together and dragged to the left holding shift at the same time to keep the horizontal direction. Smart guides = ON help to stop at the right place.

In illustrator one makes vector shape works maybe more easily due more flexible path tools, but just in this case nothing complex is needed. The problem in Photoshop is the result isn't a freely scalable vector and, of course, poor path tools for complex jobs. The advantage of Photoshop is the possibility to edit & create rich bitmap images and use them as fill and stroke colors.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that with the pen tool and more easier in illustrator. How good are you with the pen tool in photoshop?

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tolM81gnBSc